# Data Cleaning on dataframe -Repetition of words irrespective of case and plural extensions

Tags: python, nltk

I have column in my DataFrame and now my requirement is:

1. Repetition of words should not be present in the each row.
2. suppose i have dog and dogs in my string only dog should be present
3. Case sensitive: even if i have dog and Dogs then also it should remove dogs and gives back only dog
4. special cases like dog and dog's then remove dog's and result should only contain dog.

Please find the below example code which i used.

1.Tried with stemming and lemmatizing the data but not accurate
2. Even used spacy and lemmatize the data then also same result

output looks abit better but while lemmatizing, the other words are effecting

```py
m='dog ran out of Dogs and Dog ran out of cat and dog''s adidas'

try:
    def stem(tokens):
        x=[]
        stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
        for token in tokens:  
            x.append(stemmer.stem(token))
        return x
except:
    print('problem at stemming')


s12=' '.join(stem(m.split()))


#####Then written code for duplicate removal

try:
    def unique_list(list1):
        marker = set()
        result = [not marker.add(x.casefold()) and x for x in list1 if x.casefold() not in marker]
        return result
except:
    print("Problem in removing duplicates")


s5=' '.join(unique_list(s12.split()))
```

Actual string : 'dog ran out of Dogs and Dog ran out of cat and dog''s adidas'
Actual Result : 'dog ran out of dog and dog ran out of cat and dog adida'

So, in the actual result it is also lemmatizing adidas which is the last word in string. it is becoming 'adida' instead of adidas

Expected Result: 'dog ran out of dog and dog ran out pf cat and dog adidas'

Need your though or help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
lemm = WordNetLemmatizer()
sent  = 'dog ran out of Dogs and Dog ran out of cat and dog''s adidas'
word_token = [y.lower() for y in sent.split()]
print(' '.join([lemm.lemmatize(word,'n') for word in word_token]))

#o/p
'dog ran out of dog and dog ran out of cat and dog adidas'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Really appreciate for your efforts and solved the issue.
But, the output given string is in completely lower case.

Suppose if i have the string with Upper case words which needs to be remain same in output as well.
Example : adidas has been given in lower case in input string. If it is in Upper case and in the out put also it should be in upper case.

Example:
Input: 'DOG ran out of Dogs and Dog ran out of cat and dog''s ADIDAS'
So here in the above string DOG and ADIDAS are uppercase. so while generating the out put also these should be in UPPER case.